# In Macbook Pro 17", what's the difference between processors?

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

What's the difference between processors here, other than 0.1GHz? Are there actual model numbers given for the processors so I can look them up on Intel's website? I'd like to see the real differences, and information seems sparse on the Apple store page. Is it worth $250 for the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [2.5 GHz (2860QM)](http://ark.intel.com/products/53476/Intel-Core-i7-2860QM-Processor-%288M-Cache-2_50-GHz%29)

   - 2.5GHz base clock, 3.6GHz max TurboBoost clock.
   - 8MB cache.
   - Bus/core ratio: 25.
2. [2.4 GHz (2760QM)](http://ark.intel.com/products/53474/Intel-Core-i7-2760QM-Processor-%286M-Cache-2_40-GHz%29)

   - 2.4GHz base clock, 3.5GHz max TurboBoost clock.
   - 6MB cache.
   - Bus/core ratio: 24.

You can compare the features side-by-side [here](http://ark.intel.com/compare/53476,53474).

The actual difference is **4x0.1 GHz**.

The links will tell you that there is **no difference besides the clock speed, cache and bus/core ratio**. Exactly the same specifications for advanced technologies, memory and expansions.

According to [this source](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html) there is a **5.2% difference in performance**. 7987 vs 7592 with PassMark.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.4 GHz CPU only has 6 MB of L3 cache (in comparison to the 2.5 GHz' 8 MB) in addition to the infinitesimal clock speed increase. Is it worth an additional $250? I would say no, but for those looking to eek out as much speed as possible, perhaps.

I'm not aware of any benchmarks that compared these two processors, but I can't imagine anything above a 2-3% difference, but that is just an educated guess.